# bitshifting 2 bytes in c from an array

Tags: c, bit-shift

So i have been trying to bitshift 2 bytes from an array that i have, I sometimes end up with good values but not all the time. So here is an example.

```
    char buffer[2]; //current character buffer to store the bytes
    unsigned int number; //the unsigned int to store values

    number = buffer[0] << 8 | buffer[1]; //bitshifting
    printf("%02x ", number);
```

I seem to be getting this in some cases.

```
    ffffffbc // the bc seems to be correct however the f's are not
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `char` was promoted to integer, with its sign bit, you need to convert to `unsigned` value before the promotion is done. So
`number = buffer[0] << 8 | buffer[1];` should be

```
number = (unsigned char)buffer[0] << 8U | (unsigned char)buffer[1];
```